# Smart way to aggregate API data async

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

I am looping through a list of objects that each have a single key-value pair, `address` which is type `string`

I want to built an object with the results of API requests for each address that tell me how often a token symbol appears. However, I think that because I'm running all of these requests in parallel, I may be over-writing the `tokenKeyValue` count. Is there a smarter way of doing this, that preserves the parallelization to keep things fast?

```
const tokenKeyValue: any = {};
let addressesCompleted = 0;
await Promise.all(segmentData.users.map(async (user: {address: string}, i) => {
  try {
    const tokenBalances = await getBalancesForUser(
      user.address,
    );

    if (tokenBalances && tokenBalances.length > 0) {
      for (const token of tokenBalances) {
        if (tokenKeyValue[token.symbol]) {
          tokenKeyValue[token.symbol]++;
        } else {
          tokenKeyValue[token.symbol] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  finally {
    addressesCompleted++;
    // Check we are done looping
    if (addressesCompleted === segment.users.length) {
      // Calculate final tokenCount
      const tokenCount = [];
      for (const token in tokenKeyValue) {
        tokenCount.push({
          symbol: token,
          value: tokenKeyValue[token],
        });
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*I may be over-writing the `tokenKeyValue`*"? Do you want the object to be shared or do you want each user to have their own? Or are you worried about something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could make all the requests in parallel and then use `Promise.all()` to wait until all the requests resolve and then count the symbols.

```
const users = [{
  address: '12 main st'
}, {
  address: '32 main st'
}];

const promises = users.map(user => {
  return getBalancesForUser(user);
});

Promise.all(promises).then((tokenBalancesList) => {
  const countByTokenSymbol: any = {};
  for (let tokenBalances of tokenBalancesList) {
    for (let key in tokenBalances) {
      const tokenBalance = tokenBalances[key];
      countByTokenSymbol[tokenBalance.symbol] = countByTokenSymbol[tokenBalance.symbol] || 0;
      countByTokenSymbol[tokenBalance.symbol]++;
    }
  }

  const tokenCount = [];
  for (let tokenSymbol in countByTokenSymbol) {
    tokenCount.push({
      symbol: tokenSymbol,
      value: countByTokenSymbol[tokenSymbol]
    });
  }
  
  console.log(tokenCount);
});



//placeholder getBalancesForUser function
async function getBalancesForUser(user: {address: string}) {
  return [{
    symbol: user.address[0]
  }, {
    symbol: user.address[1]
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

> ```
> addressesCompleted++;
> // Check we are done looping
> if (addressesCompleted === segment.users.length)
> ```

just move that code after the `await Promise.all(…)`:

```
const tokenKeyValue: Record<string, number> = {};
await Promise.all(segmentData.users.map(async (user: {address: string}) => {
  try {
    const tokenBalances = await getBalancesForUser(user.address);

    for (const token of tokenBalances || []) {
      tokenKeyValue[token.symbol] ??= 0
      tokenKeyValue[token.symbol] += 1;
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}));

// Calculate final tokenCount
const tokenCount = Object.entries(tokenKeyValue).map(([symbol, value]) => ({symbol, value}));
```